# How to change column name and value in mat table

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in Angular. I am using Angular CLI 8.1.0.

I have 2 api: Example:

> For bank details:

```
 [
        {
            "strAccountHolderName": "Sarika Gurav",
            "strAccountNumber": "21563245632114531",
            "bankName": "IFSC",
            "ifsc": "IFSC00014",
            "branch": "Tardeo"
        }
    ]
```

> For KYC details

```
[
    {
        "strCompanyRegNumber": "123456",
        "strGSTNumber": "11242",
        "strAadharNumber": "3412345667",
        "createdOn": "2020-02-01 09:29:19.723600"
    }
]
```

I have a mat table on 1st page on which list of request is there for bank and kyc. When I click on suppose any "bank" row then on next page above information should be display. 
I am able to display above API on my HTML Page.
But I want to display it on my mat table.

I want to change column name also according to request.

Now on my mat table if request is for bank then I want to display suppose only "bank" details.
I want to display information like this:

```
Account Holder Name:Sarika Gurav
Account Number: 21563245632114531
Bank Name: IFSC
```

And if request is for KYC

```
Company Registration Number: 123456
GST Number: 11242
Aadhar Number: 3412345667
```

> approval.component.html

```
<h5>Additional Details</h5>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="additionalDetailsDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="item">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let services" class="item-name"> {{services.item}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let services"> {{services.value}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: additionalDetailsDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

> approval.component.ts

```
this.apiService.getVendorById(col,id,rid)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.result = data[0]; 
      });
```

In "result" I am getting those api.

I am able to display on html page like this: `{{result?.strAccountHolderName}}`

Is there any way to change the column name dynamically on mat table?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please create stackblitz for this.. If there is a working example then it would be better for giving solution.. You could also fork this sample stackblitz which has mat table https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-columns-mat-table-j3sbjv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make changes in your html file:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="item-name"> {{element.key}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

in your ts file

```
 interface Data {
      key: string;
      value: string;
    }
dataSource: Data[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['key', 'value'];

 this.apiService.getVendorById(col,id,rid)
      .subscribe(data=>{
      this.result = data[0];

      const newdata: Data[] = [];
      for (const prop in this.result) {
      newdata.push({
      key: [prop],
      value: this.result[prop],
      })
      }     
      this.dataSource = newdata;


});
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a column name:

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="additionalDetailsDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="item">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
              INSERT YOUR COLUMN HEADER NAME HERE
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let services" class="item-name"> {{services.item}} </td>
        </ng-container>
...
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: additionalDetailsDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

I was not sure about what you want to achive in the next part. But maybe you want an [Expandable row](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbjevgmxmqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)? 
[image: "openable" table rows, if you click on a row, it expands, allowing some place to display additional data]

Check out https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples and "Expandable row" section for how to implement it.

Comment: No it's not like that. On my first page there is mat table on which there are list of request of bank and kyc. on row click event , it retrieves the data from PHP MYSQL backed in JSON format. For kyc it returns different json, and for bank it returns different json. I want to display that json in key value format on above table. I want to change the key and value both according to request i.e bank or kyc. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question 100%, but if you only need to change the column name you can manipulate this by adding a mat-header :

```
<h5>Additional Details</h5>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="additionalDetailsDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z1">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="item">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ services.header }}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let services" class="item-name"> {{services.item}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let services"> {{services.value}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: additionalDetailsDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

If you want to change the table comluns dynamically this is not as straight forward. As far as I know there are two options.

1. You can wire up all potential columns you might need in the .html and .ts and dynamically change which columns are displayed by manipulating the "additionalDetailsDisplayedColumns" in your typescript file
2. If you do not know all columns in advance or it is not feasible to build all of them in advance you can recreate the table on user input. In this  scenario you can use @Input to hand over the columns. If you use @Input you can do that eith column names baut also any content. As changes are going to rebuild your table.